# How to fix "invalid argument" error in LESS

Tags: internet-explorer, less, invalid-argument

How can I fix "invalid argument" in LESS when using IE?

Comment: provide more details about the error. also, Developer Tools for IE might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove all the special characters (á, ã, â, ç, etc.) from the comments in the .less file.